# Regex in java for password validation

Tags: java, regex, validation

Im using a regex for password validation :
this regex is not created by me..

```
 public final Pattern PASSWORD = Pattern.compile("[(?=.*[a-zA-Z])]"
                + "[(?=.*d)]" + "[(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9s])]" + "[.{6s,}]");
```

i m trying to create a regex for
 Password which is 6 letters long, one number and one upper case letter

i dont know how to read regex...
suggest some tutorials for learning regex and 
does pattern PASSWORD satisfies my condition..
if not then what changes do i need to make in my regex

Comment: have you googled it yet?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html one of best places to learn regex

Answer (score 3):

First thing i googled shows an example of using regex to validate passwords: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you have character classes `[...]` around your expressions. This might work better:

```
"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]).{6,}"
```

I also changed `d` to `\\d` and `s` to `\\s`.

This means:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])        At least one character in [a-zA-Z]
(?=.*\d)              At least one digit.
(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])  At least one character that's not in [a-zA-Z0-9\s]
.{6,}                 At least 6 characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in one line:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,})
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have there it's very, very strange. I won't go into too much detail here as tutorials like pointed out by Pshemo in the comment are much better suited for that.

For your requirements you can use

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{6}$
 ↑          ↑       ↑
 │          │       six characters in total
 │          at least one digit
 at least one upper-case letter
```